# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session - occurs rarely

Tags: java, hibernate, flush

My batch program throws a `LazyInitializationException` exception. This does not happen every time. It happens rarely and when the batch is re-run, the records are getting processed without errors.

I'm flushing the cache for every 100 records processed by using the below code

```
private void flushHibernateCache() {
    final String CM_FLUSH_HBM_CHACHE = "flushHibernateCache";
    final String CM_CLEAR_HBM_CHACHE = "clearHibernateCache";
    BigInteger sessionLimit = getParameters().getSESSION_FLUSH_LIMIT();
    if (notNull(sessionLimit) && recordsProcessed.mod(sessionLimit).intValue() == 0) {
        FrameworkSession session = (FrameworkSession) SessionHolder.getSession();
        session.flush(CM_FLUSH_HBM_CHACHE);
        session.clear(CM_CLEAR_HBM_CHACHE);
    }
}
```

When I increase the number of records to flush from 100 to a number that is greater than the actual number of records to process, then the batch runs without errors.

Below is the error log:

```
18:21:53,687 [BATCHWorker:2] ERROR (com.splwg.base.support.cluster.ClusteredExecutionContext) An error has occurred while processing distributed grid work.  A rollback will be issued.  Processing of other work will continue.
com.splwg.base.api.batch.ThreadAbortedException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractCommitStrategy.handleReplayableCommit(AbstractCommitStrategy.java:219)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractCommitStrategy.__AW_doCommit(AbstractCommitStrategy.java:201)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractCommitStrategy.doCommit(AbstractCommitStrategy.java)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractCommitStrategy.__AW_concreteExecuteWork(AbstractCommitStrategy.java:75)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractCommitStrategy.concreteExecuteWork(AbstractCommitStrategy.java)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.CommitEveryUnitStrategy.concreteExecuteWork(CommitEveryUnitStrategy.java:36)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractExecutionStrategy.__AW_executeWork(AbstractExecutionStrategy.java:243)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractExecutionStrategy.executeWork(AbstractExecutionStrategy.java)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.JavaBatchWork.executeThreadWork(JavaBatchWork.java:109)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.JavaBatchWork.access$300(JavaBatchWork.java:29)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.JavaBatchWork$DoExecuteWorkInSession.doBatchWorkInSession(JavaBatchWork.java:92)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.BatchWorkInSessionExecutable.__AW_run(BatchWorkInSessionExecutable.java:62)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.BatchWorkInSessionExecutable.run(BatchWorkInSessionExecutable.java)
    at com.splwg.base.support.batch.JavaBatchWork.doExecuteWork(JavaBatchWork.java:51)
    at com.splwg.base.support.grid.AbstractGridWork.executeWork(AbstractGridWork.java:72)
    at com.splwg.base.support.cluster.ThreadWork.processBatchWork(ThreadWork.java:54)
    at com.splwg.base.support.cluster.BatchWorkManager.processWork(BatchWorkManager.java:78)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.commonj.WorkManager$ScheduleWork.__AW_run(WorkManager.java:2266)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.commonj.WorkManager$ScheduleWork.run(WorkManager.java)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.InvocationService.__AW_onInvocationRequest(InvocationService.CDB:12)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.InvocationService.onInvocationRequest(InvocationService.CDB)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.InvocationService$InvocationRequest.run(InvocationService.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$WrapperTask.run(DaemonPool.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$WrapperTask.run(DaemonPool.CDB:32)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$Daemon.__AW_onNotify(DaemonPool.CDB:65)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$Daemon.onNotify(DaemonPool.CDB)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.__AW_run(Daemon.CDB:51)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.cglib.proxy.pojo.CGLIBLazyInitializer.invoke(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c8ddfe27.getThreads(<generated>)
    at com.splwg.base.domain.batch.batchRun.BatchThread_Per.getOwningLists(BatchThread_Per.java:191)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.__AW_registerChange(FrameworkSession.java:1694)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.registerChange(FrameworkSession.java)
    at com.splwg.base.support.api.AbstractBusinessEntity.registerChange(AbstractBusinessEntity.java:153)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.__AW_registerChanges(FrameworkSession.java:1303)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.registerChanges(FrameworkSession.java)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.setDTOCalled(FrameworkSession.java:1290)
    at com.splwg.base.support.api.AbstractBusinessEntity.completeSetAbstractDTO(AbstractBusinessEntity.java:166)
    at com.splwg.base.support.api.AbstractBusinessEntity$2.run(AbstractBusinessEntity.java:281)
    at com.splwg.base.support.api.AbstractBusinessEntity$JumpToFrameworkRunner.run(AbstractBusinessEntity.java:372)
    at com.splwg.base.support.interception.SessionInterceptionManager.notifyGenericCallStackJump(SessionInterceptionManager.java:290)
    at com.splwg.base.support.context.FrameworkSession.notifyGenericCallStackJump(FrameworkSession.java:2311)
    at com.splwg.base.support.api.AbstractBusinessEntity.executeCallStackJump(AbstractBusinessEntity.java:298)
    at com.splwg.base.support.api.AbstractBusinessEntity.setDTOEtc(AbstractBusinessEntity.java:284)
    at com.splwg.base.domain.batch.batchRun.BatchThreadInstance_Per.setDTO(BatchThreadInstance_Per.java:124)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractExecutionStrategy.updateUnitsProcessed(AbstractExecutionStrategy.java:140)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractExecutionStrategy.updateRestartDataAndCommit(AbstractExecutionStrategy.java:112)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractCommitStrategy.saveRestartDataAndCommit(AbstractCommitStrategy.java:259)
    at com.splwg.base.api.batch.AbstractCommitStrategy.__AW_doCommit(AbstractCommitStrategy.java:191)
    ... 27 more
```

I'm not able to identify why this error is occuring. Please help.

Comment: you are somewhere working on a relation with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. You have to bind a DB-Session to your function in order to fetch your relations.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call BatchThread_Per.getOwningLists() without hibernate session somewhere.

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`  is common error in Hibernate. It is throws when you are trying to initialize hibernate objects out of scope of hibernate session.

Please, check your code.

Comment: Hi Mike. But I'm not using BatchThread_Per.getOwningLists() in my code at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: you are using it. check your error log  com.splwg.base.domain.batch.batchRun.BatchThread_Per.getOwningLists  check the place where it was called

Comment: That is been called from the base package. I'm not invoking it from my custom code.